# Error:(13, 8) error: class MainActivity is public, should be declared in a file named MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, activity

Приделываю к кнопке `call` системное событие звонка в Android Studio.

Получил 2 ошибки:

1. > Error:(13, 8) error: class MainActivity is public, should be declared in a file named MainActivity.java
2. > Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
   >   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

**main.java**:

```
package ru.startandroid.develop.p0311simpleintents;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.tesha.androidseller.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    Button btnCall;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCall);


        btnCall.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnCall:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:12345"));
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Call">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

Класс `MainActivity` должен быть в файле `MainActivity.java`. А у вас он называется `Main_acseller`.